# Backup Transaction Log since last full backup (Striped)

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am attempting to do a poor mans log shipping, manually. I need to move a rather large database from one host, to a VM in Azure. The database is currently 16Gb, and  we need to do the switch over within an hour.

**Note that Replication, Mirroring and Log Shipping are not options due to issues we have run into, and this manual process is what I need to try and achieve.**

What I am attempting is to do a full backup the database a few weeks before, using striping of the bak files (So that if a copy fail happens, it's not the full 16Gb we need to restart the copy of), and copy those files of the full backup over a period of a few days.

For my full backup, I am trying to span the backup file over 15 files:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyProductionDatabase
TO 
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_01.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_02.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_03.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_04.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_05.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_06.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_07.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_08.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_09.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_10.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_11.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_12.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_13.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_14.bak',
DISK='E:\BackupTrial\V5_DEV_FULL_15.bak'
WITH FORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'V5_DEV_FullBackup',
  MEDIADESCRIPTION = 'Striped media set for V5_DEV database';
GO
```

Then restore that database on the new VM in Azure (Virtual Machine, with SQL Server on it, as I am not sure I can go direct BAK file to AzureSQL).

And then daily or weekly (The database has low usage), do log file backups and copy those backups to the new host and restore. So basically, manually trying to keep the databases in sync.

On go-live day, do a final log file backup on the current host, copy that final bak file to the new host, and then both DBs should be in sync, with only small daily copies.

Then switch the site to use the new DB.

But I am stuck:

The MS example is:

```
BACKUP LOG AdventureWorks2012  
   TO MyAdvWorks_FullRM_log1;  
GO
```

And it says:

> This example creates a transaction log backup for the
>   AdventureWorks2012 database to the previously created named backup
>   device, MyAdvWorks_FullRM_log1.

I'm unsure what they mean by "previously created backup device". I have numerous filenames, because of the striping. How do I do a log file backup, of my full backup?

There may be other backup processes that go on on this database. Will this cause me issues with the log file backups (Another full backup of the database might clear my transaction log before I get my backup done?) How should my daily log file backup look?

Comment: What does your current backup schedule look like? How often do you do full, differential, and log backups? One or more of those may be "we don't do those". Just trying to get a sense of how much of your current solution is amortizable towards this effort.

Comment: you can backup with `COMPRESSION` to reduce the backup size

Comment: All databases in the box are backed up nightly. Unfortunately, they use a SSIS package to do these backups, so I'm not sure how to tell the type of backup being performed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unsure what they mean by "previously created backup device".

This means that in tis example they previously created virtual backup device.
So now instead of using syntax `backup...**to disk** =...` they use

```
backup ...to <device_name>
```

You can completely ignore this and backup log to differen files as all the world do:

```
BACKUP LOG AdventureWorks2012  
   TO disk = 'V:\backups\log\AdventureWorks2012_20190918.trn;
```

I have numerous filenames, because of the striping. How do I do a log file backup, of my full backup?

`Log backup` is not done "of full backup".
First you create a "base" by taking `full backup`, and it doesn't matter if you stripe it into many files or not, then you take `log backup` (`log backups` generally are pretty small and you don't need to strip)

> There may be other backup processes that go on on this database.  Will
>   this cause me issues with the log file backups (Another full backup of
>   the database might clear my transaction log before I get my backup
>   done?)

`Full backups` are not a problem for you as they just create other "bases" from which you can start your `restore chain`. You will have problems if others take `log backups`, as it will interrupt `log backup chain` (it's not `full backup` to clear the log, log truncation is done only by `log backups`).

You should talk to those who take these `log backups` if they can take them with copy_only: [Copy-Only Backups (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)
or if they can leave these backups for you on some disk.